# Transformer function not working for Seldon Core

Tags: kubernetes, kubeflow, seldon

I'm testing Seldon Core and I have a sample model up and running with only `predict` function in my serving model `MyModel(object)`. 
Now, I added `transform_input` function to preprocess input data before sending the input to the class. Again I deployed the model and it seemed working perfectly but I found that `transform_input` is not working or it's not used.
I have found the [doc](https://docs.seldon.io/projects/seldon-core/en/latest/python/python_component.html) and [example](https://github.com/SeldonIO/seldon-core/blob/master/examples/transformers/mean_transformer/MeanTransformer.py) but it only shows to add the function `transform_input`. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Even if your model already provides a `transform_input` function, you still need to add it as a `TRANSFORMER` node in your inference graph. For your particular case, you would need to define a graph like the following one:

```yaml
  graph:
    name: my-input-transformer
    type: TRANSFORMER
    children:
      - name: my-model
        type: MODEL
```

Both nodes (`my-model` and `my-input-transformer`) would point to the same Docker image.